# VueJS 2 Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined with debounce

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to debounce a function from running for 500ms. Following the documentation here:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#debounce-Param-Attribute-for-v-model-removed

```
    methods: {
        // Get the data needed for this page
        fetchData: _.debounce(function () {
            this.$http.get('widgets/quickfindordernumber/' + this.quickFindOrderNumber).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.body)
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }, 500)
    }
```

But when running this function I get an error in the console `Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined` I have tried removing the _. in front of debounce but it says debounce is not defined either.

Comment: _ is underscore or lodash, an external library, not Vue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the example, VueJS use the `debounce` function from external library like underscoreJS or lodash.

To works with it, you just include this in your file (after install this in your npm modules) like this :

```
import _ from 'lodash';

new Vue({
    // ...
    methods: {
        // Get the data needed for this page
        fetchData: _.debounce(function () {
            this.$http.get('widgets/quickfindordernumber/' + this.quickFindOrderNumber).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.body)
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }, 500)
    }
});
```